# Adding Dynamic HTML5 editor

Tags: jquery, html

I am developing a website in which i have to add html 5 WYSIWYG dynamically means client can add more and more editors fields as much he wants all the things are working html5 editor is being added as many time as want but the problem is that at fist when the page loads there is by default one html5 editor field that is good but when i add more html5 editor fields the editor becomes disable and i am unable to write any thing on it. Here is the code of HTML:

```
 <div class="multi-field-wrapper">
                <div class="multi-fields">
                    <div class="multi-field">
                        <input type="text" name="title[]" required class="form-control" placeholder="Title of description">
                        <textarea id="compose-textarea" name="more_reason[]" style="height: 150px" placeholder="Description" required class="form-control"></textarea>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning pull-right remove-field" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">Remove</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right add-field" style="margin-right: 10px; margin-top: 10px;">Add field</button>
            </div>
```

and here is the js code that adds more html 5 editor

```
function add_field() {

    jQuery('.multi-field-wrapper').each(function () {
        var $wrapper = jQuery('.multi-fields', this);
        jQuery(".add-field", $(this)).click(function (e) {
            jQuery('.multi-field:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true).appendTo($wrapper).find('input').val('').focus();
        });
        jQuery('.multi-field .remove-field', $wrapper).click(function () {
            if (jQuery('.multi-field', $wrapper).length > 1)
                jQuery(this).parent('.multi-field').remove();
        });
    });

}
```

to look more for getting the best idea here is the screen shot

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAAbe.png)

first one works fine all others below that are disabled

Comment: How does this work `.find('body')`? A suggestion - you can have click handlers defined on actual selectors rather than defining them inside `.each()`

Comment: sorry i removed tat

Comment: that was not included

Comment: if i remove the js html5 function and keep the textarea simple that works all fine but i want html5 editors to be added dynamic and working

Comment: You are cloning with the data attached of the elements, so the instance of the textarea wysiwyg editor will be duplicated and you'll obtain conflicts because it's not the same instance. My suggestion is that you make a template with `display: none` with the structure you need to clone, and then initialize each independently.

Comment: The clonation with the data is the parameter that you set to true: `.clone(true)`, You need to put `.clone()` or `.clone(false)`

Comment: how if you know the solution kindly share

Comment: For dynamic elements and click events on them to work use *Event Delegation*

Comment: sir display:none is added by default in the class i have checked that

Comment: clone() or clone(false) is not working

Comment: First: it's better if you provide a working example (as the [**stackoverflow rules**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) said). Second: if you use clone, you will obtain duplicated ids that's not correct. Third: If you write the template outside with `display:none` you can clone safely without appended data and created instances. Fourth: when you append the cloned element, you need to initialize independently. Just this. I can't provide you a perfect working code since you don't provide us the same.

Comment: i have added example here https://jsfiddle.net/waleedikhlaq1122/yjo2v31r/5/ its not picking up html5 editor settings but code is avaliable hope this will fine for you to check error